# Array operations java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got following string which I'd like to be an array:

```
 "["Arr1","Arr2"]"
```

I need to remove first and last chars in order to have

```
 ["Arr1","Arr2"].
```

I was trying with slice function like that:

```
var result = arr.slice(1, -1) but I got ""Arr1","Arr2"".
```

Any ideas how to handle it?

Comment: What do you expect ? The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument

Comment: first character was always `[` not `"`, it just appear that way in console

Comment: I expected this ["Arr1","Arr2"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from string to that array use `JSON.parse(json_string)`, this does not have anything to do with removing characters from string.

Comment: @arth81 if this is the solution - then consider marking it so